GML to Geometry parsing issue Java
I am converting GML, that includes wrappers, into Geometry objects. Currently I have converting a Point from the GML to Geometry working but the Line strings and polygons are not being parsed correctly.
Using xpath to create a relevant node list of all the xml sections I care about, and using the Geotools Parser to create an Object based off that with the GML Configuration. With Point it creates and Object that is an instanceof Geometry - so that can be cast easily. But with line string and polygon the return type of parsedObject is a String...
What I have tried:

Adjusting nodeToString
Converting node -> string -> inputStream
Confirming that xpath is in fact returning nodes

Is this geotools parsing problem or does JTS not recognize it?
If I try to cast it no matter what I get this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Relevant code and examples:
import org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration;

import org.geotools.xsd.Parser;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.*;
// relevant xpath stuff
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//n1:geometry//n2:pointProperty");


private static Geometry extractAndHandleGeometries(NodeList geometryNodes) throws Exception {
    List<Geometry> geometries = new ArrayList<>();
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

    // Use GeoTools to parse each GML node
    GMLConfiguration configuration = new GMLConfiguration();
    Parser parser = new Parser(configuration);

    for (int i = 0; i < geometryNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        // Directly pass the node's content to the parser
        // String gml = parser.encodeToString(geometryNodes.item(i));
        String geoNode = nodeToString(geometryNodes.item(i));

        Object parsedObject = parser.parse(new StringReader(nodeToString(geoNode)));

        if(parsedObject instanceof Geometry){
            Geometry geometry = (Geometry) parsedObject;
            geometries.add(geometry);
        }
    }
    return geometryFactory.createGeometryCollection(geometries.toArray(new Geometry[0]));
    
}

public static String nodeToString(Node node) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));

    return writer.getBuffer().toString();
}

}
This is the sample data I am working with:


<n1:geometry>
    <n2:pointProperty>
        <n2:maskReference />
        <n2:Point gml:id="ID2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" srsDimension="2">
            <gml:pos srsName="http://www.altova.com/" srsDimension="2">40.682432 -74.043333</gml:pos>
        </n2:Point>
    </n2:pointProperty>
</n1:geometry>
<n1:geometry>
    <n2:curveProperty xlink:type="simple">
        <n2:Curve gml:id="ID101" srsName="EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
            <gml:segments>
                <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
                    <gml:segments>
                        <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
                            <gml:pos>37.0 -122.0</gml:pos>
                            <gml:pos>37.5 -121.5</gml:pos>
                            <gml:pos>38.0 -121.0</gml:pos>
                        </gml:LineStringSegment>
                    </gml:segments>
                </gml:LineStringSegment>
            </gml:segments>
        </n2:Curve>
    </n2:curveProperty>
</n1:geometry>



And this is the return result of entering in the linestring xml chunk into nodetostring:


<n2:curveProperty xmlns:xlink= http:// www.w3.org/ 1999/ xlink xlink:type="simple" xmlns:n2= http:// www.iho.int/ s100gml/ 5.0>
    <n2:Curve xmlns:gml= http:// www.opengis.net/ gml/ 3.2 gml:id="ID101" srsDimension="2" srsName="EPSG:4326">
        <gml:segments>
            <gml:LineStringSegment interpolation="linear">
                <gml:pos>37.0 -122.0</gml:pos>
                <gml:pos>37.5 -121.5</gml:pos>
                <gml:pos>38.0 -121.0</gml:pos>
            </gml:LineStringSegment>
        </gml:segments>
    </n2:Curve>
</n2:curveProperty>




I can't be sure but it looks like you are parsing GML3 with a GML 2 parser

Just edited the code snippet - I am using the parser from the geotools xsd package - and the gmlconfig from the geotools.gml3 package. Are these the correct packages?

I used this documentation- https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/xml/geometry.html and changed the parser and config declarations to this and it still didn't work : org.geotools.xsd.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration();
org.geotools.xsd.Parser parser = new org.geotools.xsd.Parser( configuration );

Without the namespace declarations it's hard to tell, and I can't remember which version introduced lineStringSegments

Have a look at the source and check the comments and package info

The namespace declarations: xmlns:n2="http://www.iho.int/s100gml/5.0" xmlns:gml:"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"

I looked at the GMLConfiguration package and it has LineString, LineStringSegment, and the CurveType classes.
